# RegExp: before or after a delimiter

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre, preg-match-all

Consider the following

```
use namespace;

class name impl... {

    use Trait;
}
```

How would I go about it, if I would like to extract either the `use` from before the class definition or the one after? Well in the above example it would be simple enough, but if it should also work on an actual code file with multiple `use` in both places and maybe not even grouped together, but with other things in between and also with all line chars removed?

It's easy enough to get them all, but I want it to either stop when it reaches the class or begin from the class. Just can't seam to get anything to work correctly.

Lines, comments and literals is stripped, so these should not be taken into consideration.

Comment: What do you mean by _"extract"_? It would be easier for us to help if we knew what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to extract class and trait names from use references in a php file. But to determain which is which, you must know on which side of the class definition it was extracted from. So my attempt is to extract first one and then the other. But to do this, I must have it stop or begin from the point where the class is defined.

Comment: Well avoiding $use is easy enough, I do this with other extractions. But yes, I should properly mention that I already use RegExp to stop all literals from the file, to make these searches easier.

Comment: There is no lines, those are stripped along with comments and literals.

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Attributed)

Comment: Use a parser. [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Seriously though, what you're trying to do probably isn't going to work the way you want it to. You'd be better off running a match against a list of known packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing blocks is not bad, but I need to get them all, incl the ones in the inner scope, I just need to know which is which.

This is apparently to much for a single RegExp to handle, so this is what I did. Just in case others reading this is looking for an answer.

Use something to locate the offset starting position of the class declaration.

```
/\b(class|interface|trait)\s+[\w]+.*{/s
```

This combined with `preg_match` and it's `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag will provide you with the offset.

Then extract all of the `use` clauses, inner and outer scope.

```
/\buse\s+(?<full>([\w\\\]+(?:\s+as\s+[\w]+)?(?:\s*[,]\s*)?)+)(?:(?<=[\\\]){(?<inline>.*)})?\s*[;{]/
```

Use this with `preg_match_all`, using `PREG_SET_ORDER|PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`, which will include the offset of each match.

Now simply compare each offset with the one extracted in the beginning. If it's lower, it's a reference clause. If it's higher, it's a trait clause.

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect `use` clauses occuring in the outermost scope, you need to remove all (nested) blocks of `{...}`. You cannot do it in a single expression (due to unlimited depth) but if you want you may apply block removal in a loop:

```
$s = <your code>;
$prev_s = "";
while ($s != $prev_s) {
    $prev_s = $s;
    $s = preg_replace('\{[^}]*\}','',$s);
}
```

Now you may collect the outer use clauses

```
$outer_uses = preg_match_all('\buse\s+(\w+)', $s);
```